# Error connect to MongoID. The application encountered the following error: 'production' database is not configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, mongoid

I just get a weird issue about Mongoid. I don't know it's the bug belong to.
I am using:

- phusion/passenger-ruby23:latest
- ruby '2.3.8'
- rails '4.2.5'
- mongoid '5.4.1'

After the container run, I access the page and the error appears. It seems like the server could not read the config in file config/mongoid.yml. Here is the error

```
App 55 output: /home/app/dashboard-api/app/controllers/api/v1/from_dashboard_controller.rb:30: warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
App 387 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: 'production' database is not configured. Available: [] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
App 387 output:     /home/app/dashboard-api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:248:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
App 387 output:     /home/app/dashboard-api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:211:in `resolve_connection'
App 387 output:     /home/app/dashboard-api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:139:in `resolve'
App 387 output:     /home/app/dashboard-api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:169:in `spec'
App 387 output:     /home/app/dashboard-api/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
App 387 output:     /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:320:in `before_handling_requests'
App 387 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:159:in `block in negotiate_spawn_command'
App 387 output:     /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:378:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
App 387 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `negotiate_spawn_command'
App 387 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:211:in `<module:App>'
App 387 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
App 387 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
[
```

But when I `docker exec -it [container] /bin/bash` then run `rails c -e production`, it connects successfully and I could query to the DB.

Have you ever encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is trying to load ActiveRecord. If you are only using MongoDB, remove ActiveRecord-related configuration as explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/getting-started-rails/#activerecord-configuration).

Ensure [individual Rails components are loaded](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid-demo/blob/master/rails/config/application.rb#L3) rather than all of Rails which includes ActiveRecord.

Comment: I checked them. The "active_record" and "active_storage" are all commented

Comment: Also ensure your rails requires look like  https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid-demo/blob/master/rails/config/application.rb#L3 and not `rails/all`.

Comment: I have just figured out the reason. In Gemfile there is "activemodel-associations" which worked fine in the last deployment, this lib is used for supporting another gem. I think the author of this gem has changed some constraints. Well, it was a long date for me to go around this issue. 

Thank you so much for your kind support, @D.SM